# Asymptotic Formulae for derivatives of the Gamma Function

Tags: calculus, number-theory

By Stirlings formula one has
$\Gamma'(z)=\Gamma(z)\log(z)+\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{|\Gamma(z)|}{|z|}\right)$.
Are there similar formulae for higher derivatives of the Gamma-Function?

Comment: May be this could be of interest to you https://www.math.washington.edu/~morrow/336_10/papers/joel.pdf